# Dynamic type relation for core.logic

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic, minikanren

What would be the best way to define or use a type relation in core.logic?

I tried something like this to get a simplified representation of the type of the form argument, but the project usage causes various issues

```
(defn typeo
  [form type]
  (project [form]
    (== type (-> form .getClass .getSimpleName .toLowerCase symbol))))
```

Is there already a proper relation for this available or should I express this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works though of course using `project` means that `form` absolutely must be ground before this goal can be called.